# How to model ringing effects?

Tags: time-series, impulse-response

There's a discussion here about modeling birthdays:

http://andrewgelman.com/2013/12/19/happy-birthday/

You'll see that there's a big dip in births on Christmas, and there are a lot of births just before and after Christmas. There's some discussion of this phenomenon in the comments.  Gelman calls it "ringing".

The interpretation, I guess, is that mothers don't want give birth on Christmas, but children have to be born at some point, so the net effect of Christmas must be zero over some interval.

How would you model a phenomenon like this?  Is there a term for this type of phenomenon?  I asked Gelman, and he said that "the impulse response function must integrate to zero", but I don't know what to use for the impulse response function, and I don't know how to choose the interval to integrate over.  I have no idea where to start or what to Google.